# Javascript: Subtracting items from shopping cart result in negative value

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopping-cart

I've got this shopping cart script that I'm trying to revise.  Trouble is, whenever I try to delete more than one item from the cart, I get a negative value.  The cart never goes back to zero when all items are deleted. I can add items fine.

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/s8v6X/7/)

Below is a code snippet of this feature.  The full code is in the fiddle as it is easier to explain by showing you a demo of the problem I am having.

```
function addToCart(id, container_id, corTitle, corPrice, credit_hrs) {
    var amount = parseFloat(corPrice);
    var hours = parseFloat(credit_hrs);
    var remove = "<button type=\"button\" class=\"remove\"></button>";
    var selected_product = "<div class=\"item \">"
            + "<div class=\"title\">"
            +"<div class=\"remove\"><button type=\"button\" title=\"remove from cart\" class=\"remove-from-cart\" alt=\"Remove Course\" ></button></div>"               
            + corTitle
            + " for $" + corPrice
            + "</div>"              
            + "<input name=\"containerId\" value=\"" + container_id
            + "\" type=\"hidden\">" + "</div>";
    $(selected_product).insertBefore("#subtotals");

    register("add", amount, hours);
    $(".remove-from-cart").click(function() {

        $(this).parents(".item").slideUp("slow");
        console.log(this);
        register("subtract", amount, hours);
        $(toId(id)).removeAttr("disabled").fadeTo("slow", 1);
        $(this).parents(".item").remove();
    });
}
```

The problem appears to be that the `click` handler attached to the remove button is invoked multiple times when a remove button is clicked. The duplicate invocation of `register("subtract", amount, hours)` causes the total to go negative. How can I fix this?

Comment: Where is subtotal scoped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you re-run `$(".remove-from-cart").click(...)` each time you add an item to the cart, so all existing remove buttons get an extra handler.

Use jQuery to parse to HTML into a jQuery-wrapped DOM structure, and then use that as a context for your `.remove-from-cart` selector (as demonstrated in [this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8v6X/11/)). That way, the `.remove-from-cart` selector will only apply to your newly-added item.

```
var selected_product = "<div class=\"item \">" + ...;

// jQuery-wrapped DOM structure
var $prod = $(selected_product)

$prod.insertBefore("#subtotals");
register("add", amount, hours);

// use $prod as jQuery context argument,
// so `.remove-from-cart` only looks in this DOM tree
$(".remove-from-cart", $prod).click(function() {    
    ...
});
```

Comment: apsillers, thanks very much!  That is exactly what was going on but I couldn't figure out how to explain it or get to the problem.  I was trying to debug it using Chrome Dev Tools, but couldn't figure out how to step into the code.  Did you use a debugger to resolve this? If so, do you mind telling me what you used?  I really want to understand how to debug my javascript/jquery.

Comment: I debugged it by hand: I first dropped a `console.log(arguments)` inside `register` and saw that single clicks were causing multiple substractions. Since code only has one call to `register("subtract",...)`, I knew that the `click` handler must be firing multiple times per a click. Therefore, the click handler must be binding multiple times to each button. Ultimately, I was able to solve the problem quickly because I've seen very similar problems in the past (sometimes by causing them myself!), rather than through skilled use of debugging tools. Sorry that isn't not too helpful!

Comment: apsillers, Thank You!  Your answer is more than helpful and I appreciate you taking the time to explain!  I vote your comment up! I was logging the wrong areas in my code, I did not think to look at the remove `click` function even though that is exactly where the error was happening!  Thank you again for the solution!